# leader not electing hyperLedger fabric raft ordering service

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, raft, leader-election

[image]

When i try to deploy fabric-raft ordering service,  it shows these logs. it starts election repetitively without electing a leader. i tried changing heartbeat time to 1 sec and election time to 10 sec but that is not working. then i tried to changing `GODEBUG=netdns=go` but that is not working too.

Answer (score 2):

If the leader isn't elected, it's probably because the nodes cannot communicate. You should enable the gRPC logging to debug level, as well as the cluster communication logging to debug level and see if you see messages being received.

Answer (score 2):

this error will comes because of these two reasons 
1. check your orderer config once again
2. enable the grpc because in raft grpc is to be true.

Answer (score 0):

Although this is not recommended, one thing you can do is listen on all IP addresses by setting `ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0`